# POST is going to 'new' and not 'create' Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts, password-recovery

So I am trying to implement the password_reset functionality into my site using bcrypt. An issue I am having is the POST is going to my new action rather to my create action.

My View

```
<%= form_for password_resets_path, method: 'post' do %>
<div>
  <h3>Please enter your email address</h3>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end
 def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Email sent with password reset instructions.'
 end
end
```

My Routes

```
resources :password_resets
```

And I am getting this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/password_resets/new"):
```

I looked at different solutions already, and since I do not have a model the @object, would not work for me. Since I am simply just trying to call to an action.

I feel like I am missing something so very simple but for the life of me I have been unable to figure it out. Many thanks in advance to whomever is the one to help me.

Comment: Not an answer, but a password reset functionality wouldn't need all restful routes. I suggest you to make it `resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create]`

Comment: Thanks Pavan, I agree. Following the tutorial it seemed unnecessary, but I was following along to ensure I was not missing anything critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: `<%= form_for password_resets_path, method: 'post' do %>`

[`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) needs an object. If you don't want an object, just use the [`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) helper:

```
<%= form_tag password_resets_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], placeholder: "Please enter your email address" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %>
<% end %>
```

This should work for you.

Comment: You sir have won all of my internets!